# Merging 2 ARM-Template conditions into a single one

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager

How can I place these two conditions in a single line condition on a ARM-template?

```
equals(parameters('noofsecurityrules'),0)
equals(parameters('newOrExisting'),'new')
```

Each condition has different value and it needs to check both the condition at a time

Answer (score 1):

You can combine conditions with the `AND` operator.

```
[and((condition1), (condition2))]
```

The correct syntax is `and(arg1, arg2)` and you can combine this n times.
You can have a look at the [official documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-logical#and).

---

So your example would be like this:

```
[and(equals(parameters('noofsecurityrules'),0), equals(parameters('newOrExisting'),'new'))]
```

Comment: I have used the same condition as mentioned by you but it's not working

Comment: So are you sure that your single conditions are working with expected JSON? Because that´s the normal way for using multiple conditions.

Comment: @sureshd I´ve checked all returning types of `and`, `equals` and `parameters` - all types should work correct for eachother. Can you please post an example json to the question?

Comment: I have multiple condition blocks in single json, and in each condition i defined multiple values to check. I have doubt that above single line condition will work or not, when we use copyindex in our json.

Comment: I have another doubt that when we use multiple conditon blocks in our json, each block use copyindex function. If any one of the condition becomes correct, it checks that particular condition block or else it checks all the conditons defined in our json.

Comment: @sureshd check out the documentation link. there are many ways to connect different conditions to each other. You can realy create complex structures with a big oneliner. But I can´t do more with such a generic description and no example JSON.

Comment: The language expression property array index '0' is out of 
bounds.' Why this error occurs when I pass the empty array.

Comment: The language expression property '0' can't be evaluated.What

Comment: The language expression property '0' can't be evaluated.What is the reason to get this error

Comment: Can you change `0` to a string or bool-flag? Seems to be a boolean value. Then try it again.

Comment: The language expression property array index '0' is out of bounds'.

Comment: The language expression property array index '0' is out of bounds'. What is the reason to get this error .

Comment: I can´t say more about it. This should work or your properties/parameters JSON is set the wrong way. Debug it in detail - line by line and each value.